# insert string into url using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website which has 2 sections and both have a members area. I would like to redirect `/members/*` to `/shop/members/*`

Is there a way i can use mod_rewrite to insert the `/shop` into any url which is `/members`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(shop/members) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)?members(\/.*)?$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1shop/members$2 [R=301]
```